# Deshabilitar dias feriados en un datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Como se pueden especificar algunos dias del datepicker para deshabilitarlos? por ejemplo, los dias de navidad, los feriados o cualquier otro?

Tengo por ahora el código de esta manera:

```
<script>
    function nDates(date){  
          var nFechas = false;
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'prueba.php',
                data: {date},
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                  if (data == 1)
                    nFechas = true;
                  else 
                    nFechas = false;
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error occured');
                }
            });
          return nFechas;
        }


                $( function() {
                    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    changeMonth:true,
                    changeYear:true,
                    yearRange: "2017:2018", 
                    firstDay: 1,
                    minDate: 0,

                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        var datesLimits = 20; 
                        var day = date.getDay(); 
                        var dd = date.getDate();
                        var mm = date.getMonth()+1; 
                        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
                        if(dd<10){
                            dd='0'+dd;
                        } 
                        if(mm<10){
                            mm='0'+mm;
                        }
                        var date = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
                        if (day == 6 || day == 0) { 
                        return [false, "somecssclass"] 
                         } else {
                           if (nDates(date)){
                                return [true, "someothercssclass"] 
                           } else {                                  
                                return [false, "somecssclass"]
                              }
                        }},




                    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo',
                    'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
                    'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
                    'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
                    closeText: 'Cerrar',
                    prevText: 'Anterior',
                    nextText: 'Siguiente',
                    currentText: 'Hoy',
                });
            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

tienes que declarar un array para almacenar todos los dias feriados alli. Asi lo logras: Lo edite para adaptarlo a lo que tu tienes:

```html
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div>
        <label for="datepicker">Selecciona Fecha:</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        var disableddates = ["8-3-2017", "12-11-2016", "8-25-2017", "8-20-2017"];

        function DisableSpecificDates(date) {

            var m = date.getMonth();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;

            for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
                    return [false];
                } 
            }

            return disableddates;
        }

        $( function() {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth:true,
                changeYear:true,
                yearRange: "2006:2017", 
                firstDay: 1,
                minDate: new Date(006, 12, 1), /** AAAA,MM,DD Fecha inicio */
                maxDate: new Date(2020, 11, 31), /** AAAA,MM,DD Fecha Fin */

                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo',
                'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio',
                'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre',
                'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
                beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es solo un ejemplo, lo puedes adaptar a tus necesidades.

Comment: Hola Luis, tu solucion me funciona, pero tengo un problema al momento de querer adaptarlo en el datepicker que ya tengo...actualmente tengo una validacion para que los dias se deshabiliten si el maximo de citas ha llegado al maximo (porque es un sistema de citas medicas) y tambien deshabilito los fines de semana. Al probar tu codigo me funciona bien aparte, y eso lo agradezco, pero al ponerlo en lo que ya tengo (porque ya poseo un beforShowDay en el datepicker con una funcion) no se como agregar el DisableSpecificDates, y haciendo otro beforeShowDay, se me deshabilita el anterior que ya tenia

Comment: he editado la consulta para que veas mi datepicker como lo tengo

Comment: Hola @rodrigo2324 que devuelve tu .PHP? porque no te funciona? que falla? no deshabilita las fechas o que?

Comment: Bueno, al abrirse el datepicker que tengo, todo funciona bien, los dias que ya tienen los registros de citas al maximo se deshabilitan, pero al colocar lo de dias feriados, el datepicker pierde mi validacion de citas y pierde tambien la validacion de que se desactiven los fines de semana y se coloca la validacion que es de dias feriados, que en este caso seria la de tu respuesta que funciona muy bien (solo me pasa esto si creo un nuevo beforeShowDay luego del que ya tenia yo...si coloco el DisableSpecificDates dentro del beforeShowDay mio, no deshabilita los dias feriados que coloque..)

Comment: pienso que no debes tener 2 beforeShowDay, porque creo que se crea conflicto. existe forma de que crees una variable en donde se puedan almacenar todas las fechas que quieres que esten desactivadas? @rodrigo2324

Comment: Ya lo he hecho de acuerdo a tu respuesta Luis, puse los días feriados así var disableddates = ["8-3-2017", "12-11-2016", "8-25-2017", "8-20-2017"]; la variable en este caso está dentro de la función y la retorno al terminar toda la consulta. Lo único que me hace falta es poder colocar ese disableddates dentro del beforeShowDay que yo ya tengo programado, es decir, no le encuentro acomodo ni colocando la variable ni colocando directamente el nombre de la función dentro del before

Comment: @rodrigo2324 Si pruebas asi:   $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
            beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates

        })

Comment: Hola luis, aun asi con el beforeShowDay dentro de las llaves y parentesis funciona pero automaticamente me deshabilita la funcion que ya antes tenia para desactivar dias que ya tienen el limite de registros permitidos

Comment: @rodrigo2324 lo unico que se me ocurre entonces es que trates de concatenar todas lasd fechas en una sola variable y poder operar desde alli, siento que ya no puedo ayudarte mas porque desconozco el codigo.